# How do I print a value obtained from a command or a fallback value if the command returns empty?

Tags: bash, scripts, sed

I have the following script

```
passed=`sed -n 's/.* \([0-9]*\) passed.*/\1/p' evaluation.output`

echo "Passed: $passed"
```

My idea is do it this **in a inline sentence** using a `0` as fallback value like this:

```
passed=`sed -n 's/.* \([0-9]*\) passed.*/\1/p' evaluation.output || 0`
```

or

```
echo "$($passed || 0)"
```

It's possible get a fallback value if `passed` variable get a empty value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
passed=`sed -n 's/.* \([0-9]*\) passed.*/\1/p' evaluation.output`
echo "Passed: ${passed:-0}"
```

Comment: you might want to link to the man page or docs of some sort, teach a man to fish and all that